# php array_walk function calling multiple functions randomly in a loop

Tags: php

I am using array_walk in a script where I can call one specific function; now, I would like to call a function randomly from a pool of similar functions and manipulate the array values. It could be a loop construct. To be more specific, they are all image functions, generating images dynamically. Another requirement is that I need to save images in a particular order in a folder such as 001.jpg, 002.jpg, 003.jpg and so on. Currently, I am saving images using the code `imagejpeg($im, "savedimages/" . time() . "-" . rand() . ".jpg", 90);` As I call a function randomly, is it possible to maintain a similar order in saving images. I need an idea how to do that.

```
$fontFace = 'AmsiPro-Ultra.ttf';
$sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])/i', $html);

array_walk($sentences, 'dynamicImage', $fontFace);



function dynamicImage($sentence, $key, $fontFace)
{
    $img     = 'green.jpg';
    $client  = new Client;
    $image   = $client->loadJpeg($img);
    $palette = $image->extract();

    imagickResize($img);

    // create a transparent base image that we will merge the square image into.
    $img = new Img();
    $img->create(640, 720, true);

    // first image; merge with base.
    $img2 = new Img('small_square_img.jpg');
    $img->merge($img2);
    $img->save();

    $color = 'D2F57D';
    pngcolorizealpha('second_img.png', $color);


    stringFunction($sentence, $palette[0], $fontFace); 

    $im = mergeImages(array(
    'first.image.jpg',
    'second.image.jpg'
    ));

    # header('Content-type: image/jpg');
    imagejpeg($im, "savedimages/" . time() . "-" . rand() . ".jpg", 90);
    }
```

Comment: interesting, you will want to use closures for it, array suffle

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
$func_1 = function(){
   echo '1';  
};

$func_2 = function(){
   echo '2';  
};


$functions = array(
       $func_1,
       $func_2,
        ..
);

array_shuffle( $functions );
$functions[1]( );
```

or

```
 foreach( $functions as $index => $function ){
       $function();
  }
```

On the last one array_shuffle, if I remember right will reset the keys, if not you can do array_values($functions ) to reset them.  Also note I've not tested this, but essentially that should work.